# Ubuntu 14.04 will not install on compaq Mini but Mint 16 will

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I have a Compaq Mini Netbook 700EA.  This has dual booted for two years using Linux Mint 16 and Win 7.  I recently reinstalled Win 7 and tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which I have on an old Dell Inspiron Laptop.

The netbook would see the initial logo at the bottom of the screen, the cursor would flash for a minute or so and then a blank screen and the green light would go out on the external dvd drive.  So far have tried 14.04LTS Cinnamon and Mate and 14.10 Cinnamon.  Exactly the same result.  Mint 16 loads with no problems.

The installation DVD works on other computers.

Anyone know any reason why Ubuntu will not load and Mint will?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a silly thing to point out in this day and age, but the [Intel Atom N270](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB) in your netbook only supports 32-bit instructions. I was a little surprised as most modern CPUs —even those 7 years old, like your N270— are 64-bit... but there you go.

If your Dell is 64-bit and your Mint ISO is 32bit, this could fully explain what you're seeing.

The fix could be as simple as downloading the 32-bit version of Ubuntu instead of the 64-bit one.

Comment: Oli, the dell is even older than the netbook!,,Both are 32-bit and three different Ubuntu distros all load on my old 32-bit desktop.

Comment: Have now tried Mate from a USB stick and same result and ,yes, it will install on the old Dell!  So what is different in Ubuntu from MInt?